# Installing image pgk on Octave on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, installation, octave

I installed GNU Octave, version 4.2.0-rc2 on my Mac[0] using Homebrew[1].

But now I tried to install the image pkg[2].

I tried downloading it and then using this line:

```
"pkg install image-2.6.0.tar.gz"
```

Then I tried installing it with this line of code:

```
"pkg install -forge image"
```

Both resulted in the following output:

```
configure: error: *** A compiler with support for C++11 is required
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/local/bin/gsed
checking for octave... /usr/local/Cellar/octave/4.2.0-rc2/bin/octave-4.2.0-rc2
checking for mkoctfile... /usr/local/Cellar/octave/4.2.0-rc2/bin/mkoctfile-4.2.0-rc2
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether clang++ -std=gnu++11 accepts -g... yes
checking for clang++ -std=gnu++11 option to enable C++11 features... unsupported

pkg: error running the configure script for image.
error: called from
    install at line 200 column 5
    pkg at line 392 column 9
```

But I think I installed GCC correctly:

```
gcc -v
```

Has the following output:

```
Es werden eingebaute Spezifikationen verwendet.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/6.2.0/lto-wrapper
Ziel: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Konfiguriert mit: ../gcc-6.2.0/configure --enable-languages=c++,fortran --with-gmp=/usr/local
Thread-Modell: posix
gcc-Version 6.2.0 (GCC)
```

What is my mistake? Or what have i done wrong?

---

[1] http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X#Homebrew

[2] http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/index.html

[0] Macbook Specifications:
MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012)

2,5 GHz Intel Core i5

16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

macOS Sierra (Version 10.12)

Comment: You are being affected by this [bug #49306](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?49306). There is a fix there, which will be part of version 2.6.1, as well as instructions on how to make a version of the package from development sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. Just download the older version 2.4.1 of `image` and installation should work as expected.

Download Link:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave%20Forge%20Packages/Individual%20Package%20Releases/image-2.4.1.tar.gz/download